# Excel: SUMIF an Undefined Range set by Blank Cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to sum a range of cells with a changing range.

```
A   0
    0
    5
    0
B   1
C   2
    4
```

As in "A" should return 5, "B" 1, and "C" 6. Some research tells my that an OFFSET formula may work but I've got no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:
Insert a column between your data columns and paste the formula: (assuming that `Col A` now has A,B,C and `Col C` has the numbers and you paste this in `Col B`):

```
=IF(AND(A2="",A1<>""),B1,IF(AND(A2="",A1=""),B1,A2))
```

Please add a header row to avoid an error on the first column...

This will fill the values and your data will now look like:

```
ColA    ColB    ColC
A       A       0
        A       0
        A       5
        A       0
B       B       1
C       C       2
        C       4
```

Now you can use a sumif or even an array entered formula like this to sum up the values:

formula in `Col F` `=SUM(IF($B:$B=E2,$C:$C,0))` (use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of normal enter to make this an array formula)

```
ColE    ColF
C       6
B       1
A       5
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @pnuts I never knew that one

Comment: @pnuts, where is that Go To Special... thing?  I couldn't find it.  Do you mind to point this out?  Many thanks!

Comment: on a side not you do not need to insert a column in between you could add a column on the right in open space if it existed. or elsewhere for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Without filling the blanks in `Column A`, here is the formula to accomplish your goal.  Assuming you want to fill out the formula (This is an array formula, please click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> together) from `cell C1`:

```
{=IF(A1="","",SUM(OFFSET($A1,0,1,MATCH(0,ISNUMBER(VALUE(A2:$A$7&B2:$B$7))*1,0))))}
```

What this does is using `OFFSET` to find the range to be aggregated.  The tricky part is the `Height` of the `OFFSET`.  In order to find it, I concatenate `column A and column B` and check if that returns as value using `ISNUMBER` and `*1` to change `TRUE` and `FALSE` to 0 and 1.  Find the next 0 and return the row number so I know where to stop adding the number.  Hope this helps but let me know if you have any question.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in `Column C` and drag it down,

```
=IF(A1<>"",SUM(INDIRECT("B" & ROW() & ":B" & IFERROR(MATCH("*",A2:A$10,0)+ROW()-ROW($1:$1),999))),"")
```

[image]

Note:- This is `not an array` formula.